# have waited for a successfull wait?

Tags: present-perfect

I read that "have waited" can be used if the wait is over (or you don't want to wait) and if the person or thing  waited is not successful.

My question is: in case the wait is over but the thing or person waited is successfull can I use "have waited"for example:

> I received the parcel that I had waited for?

Comment: Your sentence uses "had waited" but you ask about "have waited"?

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is correct.

The sentence "I have waited for the parcel" doesn't imply that you have received it or that you haven't received it.

All three are possible:

> I had waited for two hours when the parcel arrived.

> I had waited for two hours when I gave up and went out.

> I had waited for two hours when I checked my watch, and I waited several hours after.

That is you can wait when the thing waited for arrives, when it doesn't arrive and you stop waiting and when it doesn't arrive and you continue waiting.

Comment: In your examples could  "had waited"  been  changed in" had been waiting "at last for the second  and the third .

Comment: Yes, in all three